# Levenshtein distance for search field with includes

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

Assume I have the following array:

```
const data = [{
  label: 'Östra Halmgatan, Stockholm',
  value: 'Östra Halmgatan, Stockholm'
},
{
  label: 'Västra Vägen, Stockholm',
  value: 'Västra Vägen, Stockholm'
},
{
  label: 'Cykelvägen, Göteborg',
  value: 'Cykelvägen, Göteborg'
},
{
  label: 'Servicevägen, Köpenhamn',
  value: 'Servicevägen, Köpenhamn'
}
]}
```

I want to have a search where the user can search for an item with fuzzy search.

The first step I took was to implement a filter levenshtein algorithm that checks the distance. I filter out all the results with a distance above 2.

The first problem was that when the users start typing, the distance will be way off. If they write ’Serv’ it gives a distance of 19, but it should obviously show the item with `Servicevägen, Köpenhamn`. I fixed this by only using a substring (from 0 to `userInput.length`) for the labels instead. This leads to the correct functionality for most cases. So if they write `Vöstra` (with a typo) it will only show `Östra Halmgatan, Stockholm` and `Västra Vägen, Stockholm` (since the distance for those two would be 2 or less).

However, this leads to another issue. If someone would write `Stockholm`, the first two items should of course be displayed. I fixed this by adding a fix for the filter function, which also checks if the user input value is included in the label string (with all strings set to lowercase).

This works surprisingly well, but I do still have one issue I was wondering if someone can help me figure out.

If someone would be on a non-swedish keyboard for example, I would need to show `Göteborg` if they were to enter `Goteborg`. The include doesn't take into account a typo (or a distance) when using the include, only from the start.

Basically, I was wondering if there was a way to write an includes function for strings that takes into account a distance? That would solve all the use cases for my case. Then I could use that function only since `Vöstra` would return true for the first two (given that the distance is set to 2 or lower). It would also work for `Goteborg` and `Stockholm`.

What I'm thinking is you write a function in the style of

```
String.prototype.includesWithDistance(value: string, maxDistance: number) {
    //... how would you approach this?
    return substring (with a distance) is included
}
```

I see a lot of possible cases where this could be used so any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out `Smith-Waterman Gotoh` or `Jaro-Winkler` algorithm for this kind of calculation. It is more precise and capable of handling typo.

You can test your comparison here:
[Test Similarity](https://asecuritysite.com/forensics/simstring)

Comment: Alright! I figured someone might have thought of this already, but I'm not that well versed in algorithms. Will definitely check it out, thanks for the tips!

Comment: Try use https://cdcgov.github.io/bioseq-js/ plugin for js. It should help you out.

Comment: I'm trying out the demo and entering `Östra Halmgatan, Stockholm` and `Stockholm` only gives me back "toc" :D not sure if I'm missing something?